# AndroidStudio Layout not rendering

Tags: android-studio

Help!

I don't see anything in my Layout, after it finished rendering in Android Studio. This is a blank project, I didn't tamper with it.
With Android N (API Level 19 23) I just get this:

> Failed to load the LayoutLib: com/android/layoutlib/bridge/Bridge : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (Details)

...but it doesn't even work with API Level 19. :(
Allways just this blank screen:

[image: AndroidStudio Layout not rendering]

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the issue by updating my AndroidSDK.
I was not beeing notified about updates, since my Proxy configuration was broken.